# T-SQL, Dynamic WHERE 0=0

Tags: sql, t-sql, dynamic

So hi there.

In my company we do a lot of reporting which needs a lot of filters and such to create dynamic queries.

This leads to us often needing to make chunks of T-SQL which may or may not have any restrictions, and its been practice here for a long time to get around this by using: -

```
    WHERE 0=0
    --insert restrictions after this
```

The reason? That way your always able to just plop your and/or on to the restriction without worrying if its actually the first thing to have been added and whether or not you need to put the and/or.

Long and short of the question - just how is this performance wise? Bad practice or generally accepted way of doing this?

Comment: run the query, display the actual execution plan and you'll find out if `WHERE 0=0` affects performance. I personally think that SQL Query compiler will strip this where statement out

Comment: Explain "get around this"... in the context of this question please? I'm also unsure what problem you are trying to solve here... are you hitting query lag? Putting "WHERE 0=0" into production seems redundant as its not going to affect the final selection.

Comment: Simple, if you don't include the 0=0 you have to logically work out in the language before (usually C#) if its the first restriction that's been added. So including it you save code to determine this. So it wasn't so much a problem as a query to determine if its good practice or not and if not why not.

Comment: Take a representative statement and run it in SSMS, and include the query plan. Take out the 0 = 0 and run it again. Compare query plans. I'm pretty sure, like @AcidJunkie, that there'll be no difference. If there is, please let us know!

Comment: I'd call it bad practice. The following code should do it and is not too much work IMO: list.length == 0 ? String.Empty : " WHERE " + String.Join(" AND ", list.ToArray()));

Comment: In practice it makes little difference, it will slightly increase the parsetime of your statements, but the query optimizer can discover that the statement is a tautology. Building queries that are just stringed along like this are in general a bad idea, but if you're concern is conditional filtering have you considered using the OPTION(RECOMPILE) and using nullable query parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not have any performance hit. Detailed answers on similar question here [T-SQL 1=1 Performance Hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049512/t-sql-1-1-performance-hit) and here [Whats the exact meaning of having a condition like where 0=0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308678/whats-the-exact-meaning-of-having-a-condition-like-where-0-0)